# Are the ends of Shingeki no Kyojin season 1 and 2 the same?

Tags: attack-on-titan

So I'm really confused right now. I think maybe I'm subject for the Mandela effect or something, because I could have sworn that season 1 of Attack on Titan ended with the smiling titan eating Hannes and Eren using his founder titan power to control the other titans to eat her.

But now when I've started watching Season 2, that's what ends season 2? I don't understand that at all. I remember that I started reading the manga at chapter 50 and onwards, because that's how far the anime had come. And that was a couple years ago!

I'm talking about this scene right here. [image]

I feel like I clearly remember having seen this, but Season 1 doesn't seem to end this way. So how the hell can I remember it from season 1? I haven't even come that far into Season 2 yet so I can't have mixed it up.

Comment: I don't understand you question : are you asking why you mixed up the end of season 1 and the end of season 2, or are you asking if such events happend in season 1?

Comment: If this event happened in season 1. I could have sworn having seen this in the anime a couple of years ago.

Comment: I always assumed Season 1 ended on manga chapter 50. I mean I remember clearly that Ymir ramping around protecting Historia, and Reiner and Bertholt being found out and Eren and everyone being surrounded. Until Eren uses his titan powers to control the titans, saving everyone. And that's the end of season 1. 

Man that's so strange to me :p

Comment: As someone who only watched Season 1, I don't know what you're talking about... that said, the answer has made it clear.

Comment: Fake memories and/or déja vu, your memory isn't perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time you have a question like this, think first about looking on Wikipedia for the [list of episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Attack_on_Titan_episodes#Season_1_.282013.29) (that works for every anime). Anyway, here's your answer :

That is not the case.

Here's how the first season ended :

> Annie is revealed to be the Titan Female. Eren and Annie fight in the inner walls in their titan forms, causing great destructions. Using the hand-to-hand moves Annie teached him, Eren defeats her. Eren, by compassion, doesn't kill Annie who protects herself in an unbreakable crystal shell.

Then

> Erwin attends a government inquiry, where he reveals that he kept his plans secret to prevent leaks. He further explains that despite the deaths and casualties of his plan and how they cannot get any information from Annie now that she is encased, she is proof there are humans that can turn into Titans living within the walls and he plans to find and use them to launch a counterattack against the Titans.

In the end

> Erwin's name is cleared, Eren stays with the Survey Corps, Annie is put under the Survey Corps's custody and the rest of the 104th Top Trainees go on their different missions. In the epilogue, a piece of Wall Sina crumbles, revealing the face of a Titan within the wall.

Directly after the epilogue, the first episode of the second season starts.

Comment: Thanx! I'm still confused how this happened, I must have read the manga and confused my memory.